# Sum SQL column with missing data entries

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

Here's a sample SQL table:

```
Account   Date                      Balance
A         2013-12-19 17:01:00.000   500
B         2013-12-19 17:01:00.000   400
C         2013-12-19 17:01:00.000   300
A         2013-12-19 17:02:00.000   200
C         2013-12-19 17:02:00.000   100
B         2013-12-19 17:03:00.000   600
C         2013-12-19 17:03:00.000   700
```

I want to sum all accounts for each minute and use the latest entry if there's a missing entry.  The result should be like this:

```
2013-12-19 17:01:00.000    1200 
2013-12-19 17:02:00.000    700 
2013-12-19 17:03:00.000    1500
```

Can someone do this in SQLServer?

This is something I've tried:

```
var query = (from r in table.AsEnumerable() let eventTime = (DateTime)r[1] group r by new DateTime(eventTime.Year, eventTime.Month, eventTime.Day, eventTime.Hour, eventTime.Minute, eventTime.Second) into g select table.LoadDataRow( new object[] { g.Key, g.Sum(r => (double)r[2])},false)).ToList();
```

This doesn't pull the most recent record if one is missing however.

Comment: What statements have you tried?

Comment: use [GroupBy](http://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms177673.aspx) and [Sum](http://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms187810.aspx)

Comment: You need to use `GROUP BY ` Account and minute of Date column and Get SUM  of Balance column :)  http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/17999/group-by-minute-and-two-minute-intervals

Comment: var query = (from r in dtCurrent.AsEnumerable()
                                    let eventTime = (DateTime)r[1]
                                    group r by new DateTime(eventTime.Year, eventTime.Month, eventTime.Day, eventTime.Hour, eventTime.Minute, eventTime.Second)
                                        into g
                                        select table.LoadDataRow( 
                                            new object[] { g.Key, g.Sum(r => (double)r[3])},false)).ToList();

Comment: What do you mean... `Use the latest entry if there's a missing entry`?

Comment: your math doesnt add up in your example.  1200, 300, 1300 would be the sums if you just grouped by minutes.

Comment: Google for group by with rollup, with Cube and pivot. Simple hint Will make yourvway.

Answer (score 2):

If the table you have given is suppose table A then :

Select Date, Sum(balance)
From table A
Group By Date

Comment: If your table is really called `Table A` then you would need to put square braces around the table name.  `from [Table A] group by...`